# React Component: Need to format an address from an API response and pass it to a component with copy to clipboard functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a react component that displays an address with a copy to clipboard icon next to it.

The address is returned with 5 elements: address1, address2, city, state, and zip

When I display the elements on the front end, I'm able to conditionally render them based on if they exist. However I'm not sure how to pass that to my CopyButton.

I started to write a formatter but I'm running into issues when it comes down to passing the formatted address in.

Here's my current code for the formatter as well as the displayed string and CopyButton component for reference:

```
Formatter
```

```
    const formatAddress = (addressLine1: string, addressLine2: string, city: string, state: string, zip5: string ) => {
        let formattedAddress = ''
        address2 ? formattedAddress = `${addressLine1} ${addressLine2}, ${city}, ${state} ${zip5}` : formattedAddress = `${addressLine1}, ${city}, ${state} ${zip5}`
        return formattedAddress
    }
```

```
<p> element with address and CopyButton
```

```
 {address1
    ? (
        <p data-testid="address">
           {address1}
           {address2 && `, ${address2}`}
           {city && `, ${city}`}
           {state && `, ${state}`}
           {zip && ` ${zip.substring(0, 5)}`}
           {formatAddress(address1, address2, city, state, zip)}
           <ButtonCopyText
              a11yText="Copy Address"
              textToCopy={formattedAddress}
           />
        </p>
      ) : (
           <p data-testid="no-address">--</p>
      )
  }
```

Comment: You say you're running into issues; are you getting errors thrown?  Bad data?  What kind of issues?

Comment: Sorry yeah the issue I'm getting is when I hit the copyButton, and paste the response I'm seeing an empty space with commas if there's no address2. For example the rendered address is: ```1234 Fiction St, Collegeville, PA 12345``` and the copy text will look like this: ```1234 Fiction St, , Collegeville, PA 12345```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        let formattedAddress = ''
        address2 ? formattedAddress = `${addressLine1} ${addressLine2}, ${city}, ${state} ${zip5}` : formattedAddress = `${addressLine1}, ${city}, ${state} ${zip5}`
```

could be this

```js
const formattedAddress =
  `${addressLine1}${addressLine2 ? ` ${addressLine2}` : ''}, ${city}, ${state} ${zip5}`.trim();
```

Also, you never define `formattedAddress` when you go to use it as a prop passed to your `<ButtonCopyText />` component.  You could call the function right there in the prop assignment, or assign the return value of the function into that variable somewhere outside of the JSX.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help!